# Search multiple items in a list for values in other cells

Tags: excel

Let's say I am searching for `apples` and `oranges` in a list under column A. If either are found then return (in column C, formula column) the price in column B.  I have found formulas close, but not what I am looking for yet.  This is a line by line calculation rather than just a total of all.

This is the formula I used for one item, I just want it to look for two items,  or even multiple items:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("apple*",A1)),"",B1)
```

How do I search for two values in a list and return corresponding cell values?

Comment: Finding one of two possible items is not the same as finding one or more items from a list of 100 or 1000 items. Please define your scope and provide sample data together with expected results that demonstrate what to do in various scenarios; e.g. two or more search terms match or *apple* is found in *crabapple*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `apple` is in F1 and `orange` in G1 please try in C1 (copied down to suit):

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(F$1&"*",A1)),ISERROR(SEARCH(G$1&"*",A1))),"",B1)
```